# Django rest framework overriding creation rises error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set the field of a model to the authenticated user by overriding the `perform_create()` method of a `viewset`, but I get an error.

This is my model:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    booking = models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='user_reservations')
    agency = models.ForeignKey('GeneralApp.Agency', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='agency_reservations')
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(ReservationStatus, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='status_reservations')
    arrival_date = models.DateField()
    departure_date = models.DateField()
    register_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    confirmation = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    is_invoiced = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]{}".format(self.booking, self.agency)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.arrival_date >= self.departure_date:
            raise ValidationError('Departure date must be later than Arrival date.')
        elif self.arrival_date <= timezone.datetime.now().date():
            raise ValidationError('Arraival date must be later than today.')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(Reservation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is my serializer:

```
class ReservationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='creator.username')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Reservation
        fields = ('booking', 'creator', 'agency', 'comment', 'status', 'arrival_date', 'departure_date')
```

This is my view set:

```
class ReservationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Reservation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ReservationSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError at /reservations_manager/reservations/
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Reservation.objects.create()`.
This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Reservation.objects.create()`.
You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ReservationSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

I tried to follow the directions in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users but, evidently, I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you try what is written in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

It was just a silly mistake: I changed the name of the field from `owner` to `creator`, but I forgot to change it in the `perform_create()` method:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(creator=self.request.user)
```